# Can Google Cloud Shell Editor (Theia) have color themes configured per workspace?

Tags: theia, google-cloud-shell-editor

I like having a color theme configured per workspace in VS Code to give me an immediate indication of the project. I cannot seem to find a way to do this in the Cloud Shell Editor, Theia. The option to set the Color Theme appears to be global; is this possible at all to set per workspace? How?

[image: Theia Gear Menu with Color Theme]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Google Cloud Shell Editor (Theia) can have color themes configured per workspace.

Steps :

- Go to Cloud Shell Editor.`File -> Open Workspace`.
- Choose a workspace/ folder you want to test on.
- After the workspace is opened,`File-> Settings -> Open Preferences`.

There are two tabs, User and Workspace.

**User Settings** : Globally-applicable settings, applied to all your instances of the Cloud Shell Editor.

**Workspace settings** : Workspace-specific settings, applied to only the currently active workspace. These settings are saved in the .theia/settings.json file in your workspace folder and can be shared using [version control](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/version-control) or by [downloading the workspace folder](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/uploading-and-downloading-files).

- Switch to Workspace settings by clicking on the Workspace tab.
- Use the Search Settings search bar that returns a set of settings
  that match your query. Type `color theme` in the search bar.
- You will see the query returns, Workbench: Color Theme (which
  specifies the color theme used in the workbench)
- Type any theme you want : Red/ light/ light+/Abyss/ Dark/ Dark+/
  Solarized Dark/Tomorrow Night Blue etc. and then press Enter. Your
  workspace is configured with the theme you chose.
- Now to be sure, open any other workspace, you won’t see the theme
  that you set in your previous workspace appearing in your current
  workspace. By default any workspace has theme Light (Theia)

Comment: Thanks, the UI change worked but the setting was saved in the `.theia-workspace` file itself (no `settings.json` got created/used). For those looking to set this themselves: it is the `"workbench.colorTheme"`.